# Store shared pointer to array in vector

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, shared-ptr

I’m trying to store a shared pointer to a fixed size array in to a vector, I want to use a shared pointer because I must pass a pointer to the array to another class that will write in the array, and I want to have more than one array because I may have more instances of the writing class and each one needs an array to write to, they will write a lot of data in the arrays so moving them is not a good option.

```
std::shared_ptr<char> sp( new char [MAX_LENGTH], std::default_delete<  char[] >() );
arrayVect.push_back(sp);
```

the vector is defined as class member like:

```
std::vector< std::shared_ptr< char [ MAX_LENGTH ] > > arrayVect;
```

I'm getting the error:

```
 error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::shared_ptr<char [MAX_LENGTH]> >::push_back(std::shared_ptr<char []>&)’
```

I have tried different alternatives but none of them have worked, could you point out the correct way of doing it? or is there an alternative that I am missing? the writing class needs an array of chars for the write function so I think I’m stuck with array.

thanks!

Comment: `std::vector< std::shared_ptr<char>> arrayVect;`

Comment: Whould not that be a vector of shared pointers to a single char? what if I want to acces something like:
     *(arrayVect.at(0))[1]
or something like that?

Comment: No, that won't be a pointer to single char. Actually, array generally decays to pointers.

Comment: Do you really need shared ownership? What is wrong with having a `std::vector<std::array<char, MAX_LENGTH>>` (or a `std::list<std::array<char, MAX_LENGTH>>` if the number of workers can change dynamically and  you thus need to make sure no references are invalidated) and passing out pointers or mutable references to the array to the workers?

Comment: @Corristo: well I think so, but maybe I have a misconception, the idea of using shared pointer was to ensure that the memory is freed after my class is destroyed and that the array is not deleted by the writer class or other classes that the writer could call. I thought it was generally recommended to use smart pointer over raw pointer, I cannot use a unique pointer because the array is used by the writer class also.

Comment: The code above seems different than the one that generated that error?

Comment: @JD.gg Smart pointers are there to manage ownership, not how many references there are. So a unique_ptr is completely fine if you hand out a raw pointer to the worker. Only if you need shared ownership, that is when you don't know which of the objects that have a reference to a shared object will use it last, then you need a shared_ptr. But in this case, having workers be the last ones to have a pointer to the object seems wrong, because then they'd perform work that isn't observable. So you'd tell them to stop when you don't need their result anymore anyway.

Comment: I edited my answer to show how you can pass raw pointers to the workers, yet still manage the lifetime of the array with a unique_ptr.

Comment: @ Pravar Jawalekar, I understand that an array is only a pointer to the first. if I declare the vector like you suggest it works but the write function in the other class is not accepting the parameter as a char, it needs an array of chars, I will try to wat can be done there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel like shared ownership is the wrong model here. Conceptually, why would you want your workers to continue to work on an array if no one else is observing the result anymore?

So I'd have the `arrayVect` own the arrays and hand out pointers to the arrays to the workers. When it doesn't make sense to keep one of the arrays around, stop the worker first and then delete the array.

The easiest way to get that behavior is to make `arrayVect` a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::array<char, MAX_LENGTH>>>`. Then the pointer to the underlying `char[MAX_LENGTH]` array that you can pass to a worker can be obtained by calling `arrayVect[idx].get().data()`.

By having the additional indirection through the `unique_ptr` the pointers to the arrays remain valid even if the vector is resized.

EDIT: Here is an example how that can work with `unique_ptr`s even though your workers also need a pointer to the array:

```
class Worker {
public:
    Worker(std::array<char, MAX_SIZE>* array)
        : _array{array} {
    }

    void perform_work() {
       function_that_requires_c_arrays(_array->data()); // maybe also a size parameter? 
    }

private:    
    std::array<char, MAX_SIZE>* _array;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::array<char, MAX_SIZE>>> arrayVect;
    arrayVect.emplace_back(std::make_unique<std::array<char, MAX_SIZE>>()));

    Worker w{arrayVect.back().get()};
    w.perform_work();
}
```

Comment: @JD.gg Yes it is, alternatively you can just do `arrayVect.emplace_back(new std::array<char, MAX_SIZE>{});`.

Comment: Thanks ! it is working now. the Idea of usin unique_ptr makes also more sense than the shared_ptr.

Answer (score 1):

Try declaring vector like below,

`std::vector<std::shared_ptr<char> > arrayVect;`

Actually, You are declaring vector incorrectly. Please try and check with above change. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<char>>` without the array notation. It is important that you then still use `std::default_delete<char[]>()` as the deleter.
Here is a complete example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

#define MAX_LENGTH 10

int main() {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<char>> arrayVect;
    std::shared_ptr<char> sp(new char[MAX_LENGTH], std::default_delete<char[]>());
    arrayVect.push_back(sp);
    arrayVect.push_back(std::shared_ptr<char>(new char[MAX_LENGTH], std::default_delete<char[]>()));

    char q = 0;
    for (size_t x = 0; x < arrayVect.size(); ++x)
        for (size_t y = 0; y < MAX_LENGTH; ++y)
            arrayVect.at(x).get()[y] = ++q;

    for (size_t x = 0; x < arrayVect.size(); ++x)
        for (size_t y = 0; y < MAX_LENGTH; ++y)
            std::cout << int(arrayVect.at(x).get()[y]) << '\n'; // Int cast to print numbers, and not ASCII control characters
}
```